# Recursive check files and perform zip if a particular file type exists

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, recursion, cmd

My Problem statement:

```
Main Folder
-SubFolder1
--1.jpg
--2.jpg
-SUbFolder2
--Subsubfolder
---1.jpg
---2.jpg
```

I have this main folder which has subdirectories and at the last subdirectory, there are images.

Now, what I wish to achieve is

1. recursively check if image file(s) exists in a subdirectory
2. If it does, zip all the image files in that subdirectory and name them as per the respective subdirectory name.

I have this command to achieve that:

```
"C:\Program Files\PeaZip\res\7z\7z.exe" a -tzip -mm=Deflate -mmt=on -mx5 -mfb=32 -mpass=1 -sccUTF-8 -mem=AES256 "-wC:\exp\" "C:\exp\subdirname.zip" "C:\exp\*.jpg"
```

Now my real issue is, I do not know how to piece all this together in batch. Read tons of questions on stackoverflow but they weren't any helpful.
Whatever experimentations I did are not at all any close to what I wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you retrieve all images using the [Get-ChildItem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) cmdlet you can group it by directory and get all information you need:

```powershell
$root = 'c:'
$7zipPath = "C:\Program Files\PeaZip\res\7z\7z.exe"

Get-ChildItem $root -recurse -Filter '*.jpg' | group Directory | select -expand name | foreach {
    $directoryName = get-item $_ | select -expand name
    $directoryPath = $_
    &$7zipPath a -tzip -mm=Deflate -mmt=on -mx5 -mfb=32 -mpass=1 -sccUTF-8 -mem=AES256 "-wC:\exp\" "C:\exp\$directoryName.zip" "$directoryPath\*.jpg"
}
```